# Storing a data structure with pointers to file?

Tags: c++, file, pointers

I am trying to store the following Class instance with pointers to a file.

```
class wavelet_tree {
public:

    std::set<char> alphabet;
    char middle;
    wavelet_tree* Right;
    wavelet_tree* Left;
```

I can't seem to find a proper way of writing this data to and read from file. Thank you.

Comment: Look up serialization.  It's a large topic with lots of techniques.

Comment: You can't store the pointers and expect to recover anything useful. Start reading here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization

Comment: You may also need to understand class factories.

Comment: btw we cannot help you with your code unless you show what you tried. Though, I fear this question is too broad anyhow.

Comment: Step one: Give an example of an internal `wavelet_tree` structure. Step two: Provide the expected representation inside the file. Step three: Give your best trying to implement the code that converts between the two. If this gives problems you can't solve, at least you have something to ask. As general advise, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: One issue with storing pointers in a file is that the operating system can place your program and memory at different locations.  For example, your memory may start at 0x20000 at one run-time and at 0x800000 the next time.  Store the data, not the pointers.  Although you can build a linked list in a file using file positions instead of pointers.

Comment: I walked the whole fie recursively and saved it in a file. Then kept marks for parsing it. Thank you all for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical recursion walk over the tree can help. I.e. something like:

```
void wavelet_tree_to_stream(std::ostream& to, const wavelet_tree* node) {
   to << "{"
   to << "\"alphabet\":\"" << node->alphabet << "\"";
   to << ',';
   to << "\"middle\": \"" << node->middle << "\"";
   if(nullptr != node->Left) {
      to << ",\"Left\" : ";
      wavelet_tree_to_stream(to, node->Left);
   }
   if(nullptr != node->Right) {
      to << ",\"Right\" : ";
      wavelet_tree_to_stream(to, node->Right);
   }
   to << "}";
}
......
wavelet_tree_to_stream(fstream, root);
```